# bundle binstubs vs rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am relatively new to Rails, and using version 3.x.I have just found out about `bundle binstubs gem` command which creates executable wrappers in /bin dir.Is there any benefit running commands from bin/ if there is already  rake task for that.For example, I would use `rake spec:models` , which I prefer over `bin/rspec spec/models/`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

As an example, when you install gems locally within your rails app using `Gemfile` and `bundle install`, you normally need to do a `bundle exec` before running tasks, so as to resolve ruby gems dependecies from the app directory, not from installed otherwise (using `gem install <gemname>`).

With binstubs, you don't need to do that.

Example: `bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production onetime:generate_report` without binstubs and 
`rake RAILS_ENV=production onetime:generate_report` with binstubs